# Getting error when trying to add a Listener to an Array of JTextFields

Tags: java, arrays, loops, listener

I have this code, I'm trying to add a MouseListener to a 2D array of `JTextFields`. I'm getting a `NullPointerException` and I'm not sure where I'm doing wrong. Here are some variables that I'm using.

```
private int totalX = 20;
private int totalY = 20;

private JTextField[][] fields;
fields = new JTextField[totalX][totalY];

for (y = 0; y < totalY; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < totalX; x++) {
        fields[x][y].addMouseListener(this);
        new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                for (y = 0; y < totalY; y++) {
                    for (x = 0; x < totalX; x++) {
                        if (fields[x][y].hasFocus()) {
                            if (value == null) {
                                value = "W";
                            } else {
                                fields[x][y].setText(value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Draw();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: could you add the full stack error please? also the full class code would help

Comment: @DamianLattenero I'm pretty new to coding, where I can get the full stack error? The code above, I put it under `private void run()` and not in a separate class.

Comment: The you just add a little part of the stack error, the part that said NullPointerException, the rest of the text, is the whole stack :), anyway, a user detected your error, so check the answer, and don't forget accepting if that worked (accept with the check box top left  in the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize all the elements in the array before using them cause this line creates an array with `nulls` inside

```
fields = new JTextField[totalX][totalY];
```

So create a new array element in advance

```
fields[x][y] = new JTextField();
fields[x][y].addMouseListener(this);
```

BTW your code looks a bit weird you create a new MouseAdapter() but don't use it. So, it will be garbage collected.

Update: You should put your `new MouseAdapter()` as a parameter for `addMouseListener()` method

```
fields[x][y].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        ... Put your code here ...
    });
```

Comment: Adding this line `fields[x][y] = new JTextField();` stops the application from crashing but the I tried testing if  it's actually listening to mouse actions using `System.err.println("Test");` but there's no output.

Comment: @Nicz Your posted code can't work cause you create but not use  MouseAdapter's object

Comment: Hate to be a bother but could you give me an example on how to do it? I'm still learning how to code so I don't much.

Comment: I'm not good at desktop apps and your code is quite strange. I've changed my answer. However, it is just a guess.

Comment: I would recommend reading a good book for beginners  [Head First Java, by Kathy Sierra](https://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Java-Kathy-Sierra/dp/0596009208/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8)

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Nicz Can you close your question?

Comment: How do I do that? Anyway this worked but I had to put it in a method that sets up my UI.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a misconception on how an anonymous inner class works, also with how the key word `this` actually works.

In your code, you say :

```
fields[x][y].addMouseListener(this);
```

by passing in the word `this` into this method, you are passing in the current Object that you're in. Meaning that the current class it self IS a MouseListener, that is it `implements` the Interface `MouseListener` and in THIS class YOU have implemented all the 5 methods defined by MouseListener OR the current class extends the abstract class called `MouseAdapter` (which it self also implements MouseListener)

So in your code, you have a MouseAdapter Object(defined as an inner class) which is completely dangling and is useless since its not used anywhere :

```
new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        for (y = 0; y < totalY; y++) {
                            for (x = 0; x < totalX; x++) {
                                if (fields[x][y].hasFocus()) {
                                    if (value == null) {
                                        value = "W";
                                    } else {
                                        fields[x][y].setText(value);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Draw();
                    }
                };
```

So solutions might be :

1. Replace the key word `this` with the new object that u've created like so :

   fields[x][y].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

   ```
       @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
   ```

   //all implementatiin code in here

   }
    }
    );
2. Make your current class implement MouseListner and implement all the methods or just the one you want to use.